# Convert struct to []byte with Go

Tags: go, tcp

I have a packet structure and I wish to serialize it into binary so I can send it through the wire.

There are many packet structures but I'll give the login packet as an example:

```
login struct {
    seq      uint8
    id       uint16
    username [16]string
    password [16]string
    unknown1 [16]byte
}
```

I've read somewhere that you can't use `binary.Write` for non-fixed size structures. But I believe my structure is fixed size (correct me if I'm wrong, I could be very wrong).

Now using this code:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
x := login{
    seq:      2,
    id:       1,
    username: [16]string{"username"},
    password: [16]string{"password"},
}
err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, x)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Gives me the error: `binary.Write: invalid type main.login`

Now, is there a way to fix this? Is there an alternative approach? Much like how you can use structs in C and send it through the network.

Comment: I guess, `[16]string` isn't actually fixed size?

Comment: @CeriseLimón that is right. I needed to write a string of max size 16 bytes, and pad it with \0 if it doesn't reach 16 in length :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two errors in your code. Firstly, your struct fields should be exported for `encoding/binary` to see it.

Secondly, `[16]string` means an array of 16 strings, not a 16-byte string. So your struct should look like this:

```
type login struct {
    Seq      uint8
    ID       uint16
    Username [16]byte
    Password [16]byte
    Unknown1 [16]byte
}
```

Then it works: https://play.golang.org/p/Nq8fRqgkcp.

Comment: While I was re-reading my question, I actually realized this problem `[16]string` and have changed it to `[16]byte` in my code. But, I honestly didn't know how to initialize it anymore. I even tried: `username: [16]byte{"username"},`. Anyway, I'll accept this answer ASAP.

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes, I did see that :)

Comment: @majidarif Unfortunately, since these are _arrays_ rather than slices, the only way to set those fields using a string is with the `copy()` syntax that @Ainar-G used: `copy(l.Username[:], "username")`.  That syntax makes a slice header that points at the `Username` array, then copies the string into that slice (and thus the underlying array, where you want it).

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using the `unsafe` package.

```
type test struct {
    a int
    s string
}

v1 := test{
    a: 5,
    s: "sdaf",
}

fmt.Printf("v1: %#v\n", v1)

b := *(*[unsafe.Sizeof(v1)]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v1))
fmt.Printf("bytes: %#v\n", b)

v2 := *(*test)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))

fmt.Printf("v2: %#v\n", v2)
```